# What are the best gems for social networking features?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

What are some good gems that allow simple pre-built connectivity and integration with networks like Twitter, LinkedIn, Facebook, etc?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Insoshi](http://github.com/insoshi/insoshi/tree/master) and [Loved by Less](http://lovdbyless.com/) are both great open source pre-built social networking platforms for Ruby on Rails.

For Twitter and Facebook specifically, check out the [Twitter gem](http://twitter.rubyforge.org/) and [Rfacebook](http://rfacebook.rubyforge.org/), respectively.

Answer (score 1):

The facebook gem is called Facebooker. It's great, and does facebook connect stuff too.
There's a ton of Twitter gems.